# Sync Pivot tables - VBA code not working

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am currently working on a dynamic dashboard. I have several pivot tables on my calculation sheet that are from different sources, but which have same filtering options (day, agent name, etc.). My overview sheet takes data from these pivot tables. The idea is that based on few slicers connected to 1 pivot I can update other pivot tables and manipulate with result on the overview sheet.

I have used the code below to sync filtering options. This code works well, when I make changes within the sheet where I have pivot tables. However, if I transform slicers to my overview sheet and try to manipulate with data, only 1 pivot table gets updated on my calc sheet, so there's only half information appearing right on the overview sheet.

The code is copied on both overview and calc sheets. Please help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfMain As PivotField
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim bMI As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
Set ptMain = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields
    bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalculationSheet")
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            If ws.Name & "_" & pt <> wsMain.Name & "_" & ptMain Then
                pt.ManualUpdate = True
                Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)
                        bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
                        With pf
                            .ClearAllFilters
                            Select Case bMI
                                Case False
                                    .CurrentPage = pfMain.CurrentPage.Value
                                Case True
                                    .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                                    For Each pi In pfMain.PivotItems
                                        .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = pi.Visible
                                    Next pi
                                    .EnableMultiplePageItems = bMI
                            End Select
                        End With
                        bMI = False

                Set pf = Nothing
                pt.ManualUpdate = False
            End If
        Next pt
    Next ws
Next pfMain

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, di you already try to modify the slicers connections?

Comment: Hi, as said, pivot tables have different data sources, so it's not possible to connect slicer connections. I can do this with code, but then it turns out really slow. The faster approach was to apply this to pivot tables directly. If one pivot table is changed, another is affected and vice versa. Therefore, the idea of adding slicer to one of pivots to control other should have worked. It did perfectly, however, if slicers go to another page, it controls only 1 pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is this line:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalculationSheet")
```

That line restricts the code to only considering PivotTables on a sheet called "CalculationSheet". If you want it to work on ALL sheets in the workbook, then change it to this:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
```

...as per the original code listing at http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/01/03/change-all-pivot-tables-with-one-selection/

Comment: Hi jeffreyweir, Thanks for your reply. I have changed this to referencing the sheet specifically, otherwise filters go crazy and there is no data applied. Code stops on ".ClearAllFilters".